# Matching expected type with actual type

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

What I am currently trying to do is create a type called `Value`:

```
data Value =  Num Int
            | Sum Int Int
            | Dif Int Int
            | Neg Int
              deriving (Eq)
```

With which I want to implement an eval function:

```
eval :: Value -> Int
eval (Num x) = x
eval (Sum x y) = x + y
eval (Dif x y) = x - y
eval (Neg x) = -x
```

My expected results should be:

```
eval $ Dif (Sum (Num 3) (Num 6)) (Neg 4)
> 13
```

With my current code I am able to test each operator by themselves and they function.

```
eval (Dif 3 4)
>-1
```

The problem arises when I try to perform the nested operations in the expected input above as I then get the error:

> "Couldn't match expected type `Int` with actual type `Value`"

I'm trying to understand the problem as I thought my operation should return an `Int` and since my `Value` types take an `Int` the next operation should have the expected type. I have been testing various inputs to see what my current eval function is actually doing and found that if I do

```
eval (Dif (eval (Sum 3 5)) 4)
>4
```

I get the expected result. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you trying to put a `Value` into something that takes an `Int`? `Sum (Num 1) (Num 2)` doesn't work because `Num 1 :: Value` but `Sum` expects an `Int`.

Comment: Apart from the correct answer you got, you may want to look into make `Value` an instance of `Num` - that way you can write `1 :: Value`.

Comment: I completely overlooked that I was actually taking in Value types; I was in the wrong mindset AJFarmer (I'll blame it on lack of sleep). My post was edited but I am new to Haskell so I'm succumbing to simple mistakes. Thanks for the tip Alec!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data Value = Num Int
           | Sum Int Int
           | Dif Int Int
           | Neg Int
```

Here you’ve specified that the `Value` constructors work only on `Int` values, e.g., `Neg` has the type `Int -> Value`. So you can’t write something like `Neg (Neg 1)` or `Sum (Num 1) (Num 2)` because you’re trying to use a tagged `Value` where an untagged `Int` is expected. In Lisp, it would be as if you passed `(Num . 1)` when a function expects just `1`.

You can change the definition of your type to accept `Value`:

```
data Value = Num Int
           | Sum Value Value
           | Dif Value Value
           | Neg Value
```

Now this represents expressions, where `Num` is a literal `Int` but the other constructors operate on `Value`s. Then the `eval` function changes accordingly:

```
eval :: Value -> Int
eval (Num x) = x
eval (Sum x y) = eval x + eval y
-- ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I just re-read the section and realized what I had done. Your explanation was perfect though, thanks!